# 4K texture looks pixelated

Tags: materials

I modeled a high poly TV where I went into substance painter and made a 4K texture. It looks normal, however, when I render in cycles, the texture looks blurry/pixelated no matter if I use 500 or 5000 samples. Why is it like this? I rendered the cycles image with a low sample count for speed. Just know, no matter how high the count is, areas like the TV and wall are pixelated.[image: Rendered in cycles]

[image: Material Preview]

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question. There can be any number of things causing your issue. Start by uploading your .blend to https://blend-exchange.com/ Then attach some pictures of your problem.

Comment: What information do you need I thought I was pretty specific?

Comment: Information like a visual image of your problem. Even with that, it might not be clear what the issue is, that why a .blend is also needed. If you want the highest chance of people helping you, a simple description with images and a simplified .blend is the quickest way. Just some advice :)

Comment: I updated the info...

Comment: I still don't see the issue. The first image doesn't tell me anything, the second is really low res and full of jpeg artifacts. I can't help unless you provide your .blend so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty blurry.  It's hard to tell what's happening here, unless it's something like mapping a hundredth of the texture to a plane.  Maybe you could pack the image into a file and link the file?

Comment: I was showing that in the second one, the textures look fine. But if you look somewhere like the top left of the TV, it’s very pixelated. When I have time I will send a brighter image with a higher sample count. My scene will be dark though so that is why it was that way.

Comment: It's hard to see with the image resolution. Could you add an image of your UV setup ? If you use a 4K image but use only a small portion of it in your UV mapping, it will naturally look as if it's zoomed in. Or are you talking about the Seam in the top left or the monitor ? This isn't related to texture resolution